how to use web3.js v2 with solana wallet adapter?
how can a web app add the common "wallet adapter" into their application?
at least using react since it seems to be the more common javascript framework in the ecosystem
something like the @solana/wallet-adapter-react package that makes is easy to add wallet support in the browser

Not a standard package, but there's a sample implementation on the web3 GH page, here.

I am familiar with the example react app that has the various bits of a wallet adapter, but that is extra friction for developers to use
